# No mic get detected as sound.query_devices() returns empty list?

Tags: python, audio, speech-recognition, audio-processing, python-sounddevice

Im trying to get the feed of the mic using "sounddevice" library in Python.

```
import sounddevice as sd 
print(sd.query_devices())
```

But it returns empty list.

I tried `arecord -f cd -d 6 test.wav` to record a voice note and it works fine. Also i checked the mic using online voice recorder tools where the mic works fine. Any idea what could be the possible error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building port audio from the source solved the issue.

Download the latest stable version of  PortAudio Library from http://www.portaudio.com/download.html and extract  it.

Create a subfolder named `usr` inside and another folder `src` inside the usr folder, Navigate to this folder open the terminal and get root access using the command `sudo su root` or `su root`.
folder.

Execute the following commands: `./configure` (make sure that ALSA library is set to YES), `make`, `make install`, and `ldconfig`.

[image]

for more detailed explanation follow this
https://medium.com/@niveditha.itengineer/learn-how-to-setup-portaudio-and-pyaudio-in-ubuntu-to-play-with-speech-recognition-8d2fff660e94